# Cross application authentication with Devise and Warden

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, sinatra, warden

I have 2 applications. A rails 3 application with devise, and a Sinatra app with warden.

I already implemented Devise with the rails app.

My sinatra application is an api provider for the rails/javascript application.

What I want now is to make warden authenticated depends on Devise.

Notice that both applications are sharing the **same** `{ databases }` and `{ cookies/sessions [:key, :secret, :domain, :path] }`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This answers you all: http://engineering.aioha.com/post/15082655842/building-a-web-client-like-pros

Comment: Unfortunately that link now just displays "Page not found".

Comment: Please update with working link. It will be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20120120033255/http://engineering.aioha.com/post/15082655842/building-a-web-client-like-pros